# Vulkan: why both primary command buffer and secondary command buffers need to set framebuffer and renderpass?

Tags: c++, vulkan

```
// Contains the list of secondary command buffers to be submitted
std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> secondaryCommandBuffers;

// Inheritance info for the secondary command buffers
VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo inheritanceInfo = {};
...
inheritanceInfo.renderPass = renderpass;   <-------------
inheritanceInfo.framebuffer = frameBuffer; <-------------
...

VkCommandBufferBeginInfo secondaryCommandBufferBeginInfo = {};
...
commandBufferBeginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = &inheritanceInfo;
...
vkBeginCommandBuffer(secondaryCommandBuffers[i], &secondaryCommandBufferBeginInfo);
vkEndCommandBuffer(secondaryCommandBuffers[i]);


// renderPassBeginInfo for the primary command buffer
VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo = {};
...
renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = renderPass;    <-------------
renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = frameBuffer;  <-------------

vkBeginCommandBuffer(primaryCommandBuffer, &cmdBufInfo);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(primaryCommandBuffer, &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS);
vkCmdExecuteCommands(primaryCommandBuffer, secondaryCommandBuffers.size(), secondaryCommandBuffers.data());
vkEndCommandBuffer(primaryCommandBuffer);
```

Why do secondary command buffers already set framebuffer and renderpass, and also framebuffer and renderpass for primary command buffer?

Must it be set to the same?

Answer (score 4):

Secondary command buffers which contain rendering commands must execute within a render pass, and wholly within a *specific* subpass of that render pass (hence `VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo::subpass`). This is their purpose.

The `framebuffer` parameter is optional and may be `VK_NULL_HANDLE`.

The render pass model essentially requires all aspects of command generation to be able to determine what is going on. How rendering commands get generated depends in many ways on which subpass of which render pass is being used. That's central to the whole mechanism.

The primary/secondary CB distinction allows the structure of a render pass operation to be defined within a primary command buffer (which contains the begin, end, and subpass switching operations), while the actual rendering commands can be built in secondary command buffers on other threads. But in order for those other threads to do their jobs, they have to know about how they're being used. Hence the need for the render pass.

Answer (score 2):

That's an API design question. And any answer by a non-insider would be opinion-based at best.

Most accurate answer (nobody seem to like to hear) is simply: because Vulkan specification requires you to.

At the face of it, secondary command buffer is created way before `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`. So if the driver might need to know (or there is some advantage in knowing) the render pass environment at `vkBeginCommandBuffer` of the secondary, then render pass handle must be provided at that point.

As for `VkFramebuffer` the specification says it is optional, but providing it **may** yield better performance.

> Must it be set to the same?

Appropriate VUs:

> If `vkCmdExecuteCommands` is being called within a render pass instance, the render passes specified in the `pBeginInfo::pInheritanceInfo::renderPass` members of the `vkBeginCommandBuffer` commands used to begin recording each element of `pCommandBuffers` **must** be [compatible](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#renderpass-compatibility) with the current render pass.

and

> If `vkCmdExecuteCommands` is being called within a render pass instance, and any element of `pCommandBuffers` was recorded with `VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo::framebuffer` not equal to `VK_NULL_HANDLE`, that `VkFramebuffer` **must** match the `VkFramebuffer` used in the current render pass instance